# Removing Memberships from Active Directory - Global Catalog or domain?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, membership

I am using Windows Powershell 2.0 with the ActiveDirectory cmdlets. I have a script that for each Global Catalog, connects to a New-PSDrive, gets all the disabled users, and for each user, removes all membership for the user:

## for each GC:

```
New-PSDrive -PSProvider ActiveDirectory -Root "" -Name myname -Server $GC
$disabled_users = Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $False} -Properties MemberOf

foreach ($user in $disabled_users){
    Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user -MemberOf $user.MemberOf
}
```

My question is the following: should I remove memberships from the Global Catalog, or, should I connect to each domain and remove memberships from there?
I know that I can get all the disabled users from the Global Catalog, or connect to each domain separately and do the same.

Is there differences? Which one should I pick and why?

Also, comments to leverage the script are welcome.
Thanks

Comment: Depends on the group scopes. If it's mostly Universal groups, connecting to one GC and deleting the memberships should be sufficient, replication will take care of the rest. If it's mostly domain local or global groups, I would connect to a DC in each domain and remove

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Where I can find more information about these types of groups? I don't know exactly what you mean by Universal, domain local or global groups.. If it is domain local, the GC does not take care of them?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Also, when I look up some random user in both GC and in its domain, I have the same memberOf value.. That's why I am so confused where to look.. it is the same to look in GC or in the domain??

Comment: Here's the article about [Group Scope](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc755692(v=ws.10).aspx) from TechNet.